# How i can listen the Salesforce Event Listener in Mule soft?

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio

I want Integrate Salesforce with Mulesoft. In salesforce CASE object i have create for Outbound Message. i give the Endpoint URL `http://localhost:8088/service`. Its not working. how it will be work.Thanks It is right?? or wrong means how i can create salesforce outbound message listener. Thanks

```
 <flow name="salesforce_to_muleFlow1" doc:name="salesforce_to_muleFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  doc:name="HTTP" host="https://na11.salesforce.com/soap/wfoutbound.jsp?aid=04kG0000000Csqa&amp;type=Partner" port="80"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Salesforce connector: http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/salesforce-cloud-connector

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Mule soft Sales force connector to integrate with Sales force.